# Sql query does not work well

Tags: filters, mysql, sql

I have a problem with a SQL query in wordpress.
I create a query that return product_ID of products that have one or more attribute.

[image]

I have highlighted my problem. I want to displya the product that have all attribute, instead with OR the function return products they have at least one of the attributes.

But if I change OR with AND the function return all product.
I'm probably wrong anything.

I share all code:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_filter_woocommerce_product', 'filter_woocommerce_product');
function filter_woocommerce_product() {
    global $wpdb;
    $filtri_selezionati = $_REQUEST['selected'];
    $sql = "SELECT distinct(p.`id`) AS 'Product_ID'
                FROM   `wp_posts` AS p
                    INNER JOIN `wp_term_relationships` AS tr
                            ON p.`id` = tr.`object_id`
                    INNER JOIN `wp_term_taxonomy` AS tt
                            ON tr.`term_taxonomy_id` = tt.`term_id`
                            AND tt.`taxonomy` LIKE 'pa_%'
                    INNER JOIN `wp_terms` AS t
                            ON tr.`term_taxonomy_id` = t.`term_id`
                WHERE  p.`post_type` = 'product'
                    AND p.`post_status` = 'publish' AND ";
    $where = '';
    if(!empty($filtri_selezionati)){
        unset($_SESSION['filtri_attivi']);
        foreach ($filtri_selezionati as $key => $value) {
            if($key == 0){
                $explode_value = explode('_',$value);
                $_SESSION['filtri_attivi'][] = $value;
                $where .= '(tt.taxonomy="pa_'.$explode_value[0].'" AND t.name = "'.$explode_value[1].'") ';
            } else {
                $explode_value = explode('_',$value);
                $_SESSION['filtri_attivi'][] = $value;
                $where .= ' OR (tt.taxonomy="pa_'.$explode_value[0].'" AND t.name = "'.$explode_value[1].'")';
            }
        }
        error_log($sql.$where);
        $product_filtering = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare($sql.$where));
    }
    unset($_SESSION['product_filter']);
    if(empty($product_filtering)){
        $_SESSION['product_filter'] = [];   
    } else{
        foreach($product_filtering as $product){
            $_SESSION['product_filter'][] = $product->Product_ID;
        }
    }
    $response['success'] =  1;
    wp_send_json($response);
    wp_die();

    
}
```

Comment: this code will never work on a lot of WordPress hosts because it relies on `$_SESSION`, a lot of WordPress hosts disable PHP sessions. You've also incorrectly used `$wpdb->prepare`, it takes multiple parameters, and it's used to insert variables safely into SQL statements, but you're inserting them directly. Also `Product_ID` is not a column in the posts table. Is there a reason you chose raw SQL instead of a `WP_Query` loop? And have you asked this in a WooCommerce community? _3rd party plugin dev support is offtopic here, you can't ask for help working with WC on this stack._

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The code is not written by me directly. I'll rewrite using WP_Query. Thank you